# How to disable-gpu in Visual Studio Code on "Open With"

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I have installed Visual Studio Code 1.7.1 on my Ubuntu Linux. I got a blank screen when I started it at first, but after I added --disable-gpu it works fine. Now if I run code --disable-gpu in the command line everything is fine. I have also changed the Exec line to Exec=/usr/share/code/code --disable-gpu %U
in /usr/share/applications/code.desktop so I can run Code by clicking on the Icon on the desktop as well.

The only problem I have is that when I have a file (let's say CSS) and I want to open it with Visual Studio Code, I right click on it and try to open it with Code I have the blank screen again. How can I add the --disable-gpu parameter there as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You must insert **--disable-gpu** on **/usr/share/applications/code.desktop** file in **Exec** after **code** *(in my example I've code-insiders that is the developer preview)*:

[image]